# What is a good branching strategy when developing several future releases at once?

Tags: svn, branch, branching-strategy

### The past

I develop a software project using subversion as an scm. Until now, development always happened in `trunk`, so problems arose when a bugfix release was necessary. Now, we want to rethink our branching strategy and the requirement is: We want to be able to work on multiple future releases at once.

### The task

That means: Assume, the current version we are working on is 1.0. The next planned version is 2.0, the version after that is 3.0. Now that we have released 1.0 we want to

- maintain version 1.0
- develop features for 2.0
- at the same time develop features for 3.0

Of course, fixes that have been applied in 1.0 are also needed in the other two versions. Furthermore, features from 2.0 will also have to be in 3.0. Also, it might be possible that a minor release is planned, say 1.1 that also includes new features and will have to be maintained separately.

### A possible solution

I came up with the following branching strategy:

- The trunk will be abandoned
- For each new planned release, a branch is created which stems from the last release branch
- Changes are propagated "upwards" in the version timeline

Let me elaborate this a bit more: In the given example, we would branch version 1.0 from trunk. Also, we would branch version 2.0 from version 1.0 and version 3.0 from version 2.0. When a change is made in 1.0, it will be merged into 2.0 and subsequently into 3.0.

[image: Visualization of the described branching strategy (please excuse the crappy paint quality)]

### The question

Is this a valid methodology? Will it work technically? Are there organizational pitfalls? Are there best practices? (All the internet would come up with is: "Develop in trunk, maintain in release branch"). It especially seems strange to me to abandon trunk -- is that wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The idea of "developing in `trunk`" comes from the fact `trunk` is the default branch you can want to checkout.
I.e: you have no idea of the naming convention for the other branches, but you know at least that the "main" branch is called "`trunk`", so as a new developer, you can be tempted to checkout that one, which is why the current development is best made in that same branch.

The branches `1.0`, `1.1` or `2.0` would rather be for maintenance operations, once those releases has been done.

For parallel development, I would recommend another naming convention, like `1.1_dev`, `2.0_dev`, made from the `trunk` (which would represent the current `1.0` development).
That can work provided those branches aren't too much long lived, and that they don't diverge too much from `trunk` (because of merges which would become increasingly complex otherwise).

Comment: That sounds reasonable. But what would happen after the release of 1.0? In that case trunk should "switch" to 2.0 and 1.0 would become a release-branch (that is, it only exists for maintenance). What would that "switching" look like, technically? Rename `trunk` to `rb-1.0` and `dev-2.0` to `trunk?`

Comment: @David: no switching involved: trunk remains trunk. A tag is created ('`1.0`' immutable), and a fix branch is created ('`1.0_fix`'). The content of `dev_2.0` then needs to erase the content of `trunk`, and the branch `dev_2.0` is discontinued.

Comment: I second VonC's methodology, all development happens on trunk. Everytime you are ready for a ready, you tag trunk, call it 1.0 and release it. If there are any bugs in 1.0 release, you branch it (say called it 1.0_branch) check in bug fix in it to do a release, merge that bug fix into trunk to keep it updated and continue work on trunk. You can make it so that every release is a branch (effectively creating a release 1.0 from branch 1.0, doesnt make any difference in this context).

Comment: @VonC: Thank you for your answer. Still, I'm not sure how to translate "The content of dev_2.0 then needs to erase the content of trunk" into svn terminology. I mean, I think know what you intend, but I do not know how to do this technically.

Comment: @omermuhammed: How would you address the problem of developing multiple future releases at once?

Comment: @David: I would go the easy way and simply make a mirror copy of `dev_2.0` content (files and directories only, not the `.svn` matadata) in `trunk` working tree, before adding/removing/updating those files in `trunk`.

Comment: That is possible, in trunk identify a revision as a stable point for start of multiple releases. Then create as many branches as you need, one for each release. Keep the most important release on trunk. And when you deem fit (usually after a release from that branch), merge back from the release branches into trunk.